# Any known issues with ActiveMQ running on SGI

Tags: c++, activemq-classic, sgi

I'm having lots of issues trying to use ActiveMQ, and was wondering if there are any know issues running on SGI hardware - specifically a UV2k?   Are there any known issues running on Suse linux? 
Getting a lot of threads started when starting the ActiveMQ service, and getting an error message stating "Insufficient threads configured for selectChannelConnector". Tried limiting the JVM thread stack size with no joy.

ActiveMQ 5.10 snapshot

Answer (score 0):

I haven't heard of UV2k, but it sounds like something with a lot of processors/cores, right?

Jetty, which is powering the webgui for ActiveMQ, uses one connection acceptor per four cores (roughly).
The default thread pool size is maxed at 256 threads in Jetty, so if you have above 1024 cores the thread pool won't be enough for jetty. A quick google shows the UV2K has "up to 4096 cores" (whatever that means, if this is the number Jetty consider - it means 1024 acceptors).

You can alter the Jetty thread pool by placing this element into the "server" bean in conf/jetty.xml. I leave the correct max size up to you to figure out.

```
<property name="threadPool">  
  <bean id="ThreadPool" class="org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool">
    <property name="minThreads" value="10"/>
    <property name="maxThreads" value="XXX"/>
  </bean>
</property>
```

Another thing you can try is to manually set the number of acceptors to a lower value, like 1 (you won't need much for an administrative UI). Look into your Connector bean (same file), and add the property `<property name="acceptors" value="2"/>`.

For obvious reasons, I have not tested the above config on the machine you mention, so consider it a "good guess" rather than a confirmed fact.

Comment: Many thanks, I'll give that a try. Our UV 'only' has 512 cores. In the meantime we stood up a single core VM to host ActiveMQ